# SQL Machine Learning Services- R Services Error

Tags: sql-server, r, stored-procedures, microsoft-r

I am receiving the error of:

***Feature 'Advanced Analytics Extensions' is not installed***

When trying to get the Machine Learning Services set up in Sql:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/set-up-sql-server-r-services-in-database

I'm trying to execute the code:

```
 EXEC sp_configure  'external scripts enabled', 1
 RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

I am very confused because I have the R-Services (in database) feature downloaded and "Advanced Analytics Extensions" is not even an option as seen below:

[image: Feature Options]

I have been stuck on this for quite sometime and not been able to find a solution.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure you are running the `sp_configure` on the instance where you have the SQL Server R Services installed? EDIT: Oh, and make sure you run the command from SSMS 2016 (or higher).

Comment: that was a noobie question! i wasnt running it on the instance where i had R Services installed. I am not used to creating DB's for myself. I had created 2 instances of SQL- both the same name but one with /EXPRESS at the end of it.Knowing that R services had to be run in express, I assumed it was the /EXPRESS version. I didnt realize both Db's were the express version until I checked after this post. Therefore I thought the /EXPRESS instance was my only option. Thanks for the help! if you want to put this into some sort of answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question in my comment above, make sure you are running `sp_configure` on the actual instance where you have SQL Server R Services installed.